# Json data is corrupted some time in ios in react native

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-navigation

Suddenly, JSON data from the API is corrupted some time in iOS in react native. It happens sporadically. My thinking is that it's due to memory issue.

POD.lock file:

```
1. PODS:
  - BDVSimpleContacts (1.0.2):
    - React
  - boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
  - CodePush (2.0.3):
    - CodePush/Core (= 2.0.3)
    - CodePush/SSZipArchive (= 2.0.3)
    - React
  - CodePush/Core (2.0.3):
    - React
  - CodePush/SSZipArchive (2.0.3):
    - React
  - DoubleConversion (1.1.5)
  - Firebase/Core (4.13.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.2.0)
    - FirebaseCore (= 4.0.20)
  - Firebase/Messaging (4.13.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseMessaging (= 2.2.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (4.2.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseCore (4.0.20):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
  - FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
  - FirebaseMessaging (2.2.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.1)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.5)
  - Folly (2016.09.26.00):
    - boost-for-react-native
    - DoubleConversion
    - GLog
  - GLog (0.3.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - nanopb (0.3.8):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.8)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.8)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.8)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.8)
  - Protobuf (3.6.0)
  - React (0.53.3):
    - React/Core (= 0.53.3)
  - react-native-fcm (14.2.1):
    - Firebase/Messaging
    - React
  - react-native-image-picker (0.14.3):
    - React
  - React/Core (0.53.3):
    - yoga (= 0.53.3.React)
  - React/CxxBridge (0.53.3):
    - Folly (= 2016.09.26.00)
    - React/Core
    - React/cxxreact
  - React/cxxreact (0.53.3):
    - boost-for-react-native (= 1.63.0)
    - Folly (= 2016.09.26.00)
    - React/jschelpers
    - React/jsinspector
  - React/DevSupport (0.53.3):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTWebSocket
  - React/fishhook (0.53.3)
  - React/jschelpers (0.53.3):
    - Folly (= 2016.09.26.00)
    - React/PrivateDatabase
  - React/jsinspector (0.53.3)
  - React/PrivateDatabase (0.53.3)
  - React/RCTAnimation (0.53.3):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTBlob (0.53.3):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTNetwork (0.53.3):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTText (0.53.3):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTWebSocket (0.53.3):
    - React/Core
    - React/fishhook
    - React/RCTBlob
  - RNShare (1.0.27):
    - React
  - RNVectorIcons (4.6.0):
    - React
  - RNViewShot (2.3.0):
    - React
  - yoga (0.53.3.React)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - BDVSimpleContacts (from `../node_modules/react-native-simple-contacts`)
  - CodePush (from `../node_modules/react-native-code-push`)
  - DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`)
  - Firebase/Core (= 4.13.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (= 4.13.0)
  - Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`)
  - GLog (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec`)
  - react-native-fcm (from `../node_modules/react-native-fcm`)
  - react-native-image-picker (from `../node_modules/react-native-image-picker`)
  - React/Core (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/CxxBridge (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/DevSupport (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTAnimation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTNetwork (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTText (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTWebSocket (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - RNShare (from `../node_modules/react-native-share`)
  - RNVectorIcons (from `../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons`)
  - RNViewShot (from `../node_modules/react-native-view-shot`)
  - yoga (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`)

SPEC REPOS:   https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git:
    - boost-for-react-native
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - FirebaseMessaging
    - GoogleToolboxForMac
    - nanopb
    - Protobuf

EXTERNAL SOURCES:   BDVSimpleContacts:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-simple-contacts"   CodePush:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-code-push"   DoubleConversion:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"   Folly:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"  
GLog:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec"  
React:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native"   react-native-fcm:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-fcm"   react-native-image-picker:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-image-picker"   RNShare:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-share"   RNVectorIcons:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons"   RNViewShot:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-view-shot"   yoga:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:   BDVSimpleContacts:
a37cd622c77337d02d19d5bebf73c3ef0e4c477e   boost-for-react-native:
39c7adb57c4e60d6c5479dd8623128eb5b3f0f2c   CodePush:
054a0d6cab22824a1002f82b5bd9694596e4d2e0   DoubleConversion:
ebb6747c5b66026ad4f97b789c3ceac6f18e57a6   Firebase:
5ec5e863d269d82d66b4bf56856726f8fb8f0fb3   FirebaseAnalytics:
7ef69e76a5142f643aeb47c780e1cdce4e23632e   FirebaseCore:
90cb1c53d69b556f112a1bf72b5fcfaad7650790   FirebaseInstanceID:
8d20d890d65c917f9f7d9950b6e10a760ad34321   FirebaseMessaging:
75cdb862e86c30e0913a2ff307e48d49357c5b73   Folly:
0e765a0b56a1bf180dcbd51ee178cd3a1e2ab986   GLog:
ed471a3ad6ad53eefb343a530f15dad283e5ef51   GoogleToolboxForMac:
91c824d21e85b31c2aae9bb011c5027c9b4e738f   nanopb:
5601e6bca2dbf1ed831b519092ec110f66982ca3   Protobuf:
0fc0ad8bec688b2a3017a139953e01374fedbd5f   React:
af66244a7d630be2aef03b4ddfe3570e4eff39fc   react-native-fcm:
7de3ba1108aba709c3d2b4237594554eb5f6f026  
react-native-image-picker: 42cfe2c8435d893414f8714a81e480313cb1412b 
RNShare: 80d4472ab25e77d9f824cb8d49d7e85af91c66e0   RNVectorIcons:
c0dbfbf6068fefa240c37b0f71bd03b45dddac44   RNViewShot:
fdf9a64f0621ebc4e7c3392a10d2ffb70a7faee4   yoga:
55da126afc384965b96bff46652464373b330add

PODFILE CHECKSUM: a472f013589e5233b32df85bc1a68994a8bf23f9

COCOAPODS: 1.5.0
```